# Como pesquisar aluno por CPF ou Matrícula nessa lista?

Tags: c#

O que acrescento nesse método GET_Alunos para poder fazer a pesquisa por CPF ou Matrícula.

```
List<Sistema.Acadiesp.Entidades.Aluno> alunos = aluno_bo.Get_Alunos(nome == null ? "" : nome,
                                                        cod_curso.HasValue ? cod_curso.Value : 0, cpf == null ? "" : cpf, cod_matricula == null ? "" : cod_matricula)                                              
                                                        .OrderBy(a => a.FK_Pessoa.nome).ToList();
```

Não tinha o parâmetro CPF e cod_matricula, adicionei agora.

Onde o Get_Aluno é o seguinte:

```
public List<Aluno> Get_Alunos(string _nome, int _curso, string cpf, string cod_matricula) { string curso = _curso.ToString(); return _DAO.Find(a => (a.nome.Contains(_nome) || a.nome_rg.Contains(_nome)) && (a.cod_curso == curso || _curso == 0) ).ToList(); }
```

Acredito que seja para adicionar os dois parâmetros aqui, mas não estou sabendo como:

```
   public List<Aluno> Get_Alunos(string _nome, int _curso, string cpf, string cod_matricula)
    {
        string curso = _curso.ToString();
        return _DAO.Find(a => (a.nome.Contains(_nome) || a.nome_rg.Contains(_nome)) &&
                       (a.cod_curso == curso || _curso == 0)
            ).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Não tem como responder porque não sabemos o que tem dentro de `Get_Alunos`

Comment: public List<Aluno> Get_Alunos(string _nome, int _curso, string cpf, string cod_matricula)
        {
            string curso = _curso.ToString();
            return _DAO.Find(a => (a.nome.Contains(_nome) || a.nome_rg.Contains(_nome)) &&
                           (a.cod_curso == curso || _curso == 0)
                ).ToList();
        }

Comment: coloque na pergunta essas observações de código

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Dá uma pesquisada por LINQ, basicamente pode usar o .Where, .ToList, tem vários métodos que você pode usar lambda para fazer pesquisas